# How do you account for the number of students in a classroom when people go in and leave?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

The problem is as follows:

> In two classrooms there are the same number of people. For every five
> people who leave the first, three leave the second to enter the first
> and one more retires home. When there are $50$ people in the first
> room, in the second there are $20$ people. How many people were
> initially in each room?

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{100 people}\\
2.&\textrm{90 people}\\
3.&\textrm{85 people}\\
4.&\textrm{80 people}\\
5.&\textrm{75 people}\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused exactly how to assess this problem?. The part which makes me confused is how to understand the fact that for every five people who leave the first and three enter the first. Does it mean that in total there are those five people plus one who retires home from the second classroom?.

I don't know how to set the equations in this particular problem. Can someone help me with this using a **step-by-step approach** so I can better understand?.

From the looks of this problem it seems to be that this problem is to be solved using a system of two linear equations, but as mentioned, I don't know how to translate those words into an equation.

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  Where do the $5$ people leaving the first room go?  Do they all go home?  Do they all go to room $2$?  Some of each?

Comment: My guess (for what it is worth) is that the $5$ people exiting room $1$ all go home, and that at the same instant $3$ people go from room two to room one and one person goes home from room $2$.  That's just a guess of course, but maybe it's worth solving the problem with those rules to see if you get one of the official solutions.

Comment: Indeed, with that interpretation, exactly one of those answers is possible so I expect that interpretation is correct.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for the late reply. Yes indeed the official answer is $\textrm{80 students}$. I'm assuming that the author of this problem intended to say that the people who left the first room will leave and not entering the second. As you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be 80, but I agree with the commenter lulu that the question is ambiguously phrased.

For every 5 people leaving room A, (as I read it) three are moving from room B to room A, and one is leaving room B to go home. So Room A loses 5 people but gains 3, for a net change of -2, while room B loses 4 people.

We are given the condition that at some point in time room A has 50 people in it, room B has 20. We are also told that initially there are the same number of people in each room. So
$$
20 + 4x = 50 + 2x,
$$
where $x$ counts the number of times at which students are leaving the room.
Solving this equation gives $x = 15$, so each room had 80 occupants initially.

Comment: Howdy! Sorry for the late reply. I'm the OP of the question. I'm sorry for any unclear statement in the question. From inspecting the original source, it seems that the author intended to say that the people who leave the first room all go home. However I still don't understand very well the equation you had just posted. When you say that at some point in time there are 50 people in room A and 20 people in room B, for the condition that both to have the same number I must add those people who had left, but **are the units of $x$?** because as it stands I still dont understand.

Comment: Typically in these sorts of problems it helped me a lot that the variable include some sort of conversion factor which cancels the denominator leaving the numerator in the same units as the rest. In the equation I think you're equating $\textrm{number of students in room B}=\textrm{number of students in room A}$ is this part correct? But if $x$ counts the number of times, what it would be its representation would it be like this $\frac{\textrm{student}}{\textrm{times}}$ or is it that in this sense "times" is just dimentionless?. Can you explain better this part as well please?

Comment: Yes, it's 'number of students in room B=number of students in room A', and $x$ is dimensionless. I'm thinking of it like a board game, where $x$ counts the number of turns. On each turn, 4 people leave room A and 2 leave room B. So, as we want to propagate *backwards* in time, I'm adding $4x$ and $2x$ to the respective sides.